# One button working, other button gives error of: "Notice: Undefined index: dbconfig.php on line 6"

Tags: php, html

I have a page that has two buttons "Yes" and "no". When I click the "yes" button, everything works fine, but when I click the "No" button, I get the error.

However, the database is still updated when i get this error but what I want is for it to go back two pages, the same way that the "Yes" button does in the code below.

edit.php

```
<form action="dbconfig.php" method="post">
<select name="studentId" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Student</option>
    <option value="35290">student1</option>
    <option value="35316">student2</option>
    <option value="35294">student3</option>
    <option value="35377">student4</option>
</select>

    <select name="createdAt" id="" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select Time</option>
                <option value="2019-04-02 11:00:00">11:00</option>
                <option value="2019-04-02 12:00:00">12:00</option>
                <option value="2019-04-02 13:00:00">13:00</option>
                <option value="2019-04-02 15:00:00">15:00</option>
    </select>       
<p>
Did the student attend class?
<button name="attended" type="submit" value="1" >Yes</button>
<button name="attended2" type="submit" value="0" >No</button>
```

dbconfig.php

```
    <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","billy") or die ("Database                                           
           not selected");

    $studentId=$_POST['studentId'];
    $attended=$_POST['attended'];
    $createdAt=$_POST['createdAt'];


    if(isset($_POST['attended']))
      {
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into attendance (studentId, attended, 
            createdAt) values ('$studentId','$attended','$createdAt')") or die                             
            ("Error");
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                   , 'history.go(-2);'
                   , '</script>';
      }
    else (isset($POST['attended2'])) 
      {
           $query=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM attendance WHERE 
                studentId='$studentId' AND createdAt='$createdAt'") or die ("Error")       
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: you are trying to get $_POST with $attended=$_POST['attended'];, but when you click NO, no 'attended' provided in $_POST. Move the line 6 ($attended=$_POST['attended'];) inside true case of your if

Comment: `else (isset($POST['attended2'])) ` this is not valid I guess. Either you should create two separate `if` statements or use `else if ()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: use else if. when you add if condition else statement is not working with the your if condition. so else state not checking any condition again. you have to replace it with else if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your code from line 6 (`$attended=$_POST['attended'];`) inside true case of your If condition `if(isset($_POST['attended']))` and use elseif of simple else

Answer (score 2):

You don't need if-else condition just use IF condition for each button.
Example,

```
if(isset($_POST['attended'])) {
....
}

if(isset($_POST['attended2'])) {
...
}
```

Comment: But it would not help him. He has an error on line 6, before if

Answer (score 1):

I think ,In the "YES" button and "no" button clicking check is not right you use

```
if (logic){
runs if logic is true;
}else{
runs if logic is wrong;
}
```

**TRY THIS ONE**

```
  if(isset($_POST['attended'])){
     $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into attendance (studentId, attended, 
     createdAt) values ('$studentId','$attended','$createdAt')") or die                             
     ("Error");
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
           , 'history.go(-2);'
           , '</script>';}

  if (isset($POST['attended2'])) 
      {
       $query=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM attendance WHERE 
    studentId='$studentId' AND createdAt='$createdAt'") or die ("Error")       
      }
```